# Unable to used private repo in npm dependencies

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, package.json

Hey Guys
I am geting this error when running npm install

```
openssl config failed: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
openssl config failed: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Users\rmittal\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/xxxx/xxx-api.git 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rmittal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-02T06_15_51_313Z-debug.log
```

git@github.com/xxxx/xxx-api.git is my other repo only
I looked into [npm install error : "Host key verification failed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806821/npm-install-error-host-key-verification-failed)
but did not lead me to solution.
Can someone plz help me?

Version used :

```
D:\>node -v
v10.23.1

D:\>npm -v
openssl config failed: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
openssl config failed: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
6.14.10
```

Repostiory are also setup properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` suggested in the answer you mention should work, but since you are in a CMD, it should be:

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/known_hosts
```

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Assuming:

- your `%PATH%` includes `C:\path\to\Git\usr\bin` (where `ssh-keyscan.exe` resides)
- your private key does give you access to that private repository.

Test the last point with (independently of `npm`), in any folder

```
 git ls-remote git@github.com/xxxx/xxx-api.git
```

If you can list remote heads from that private repository, that means you do have access to it.
And it should ask to add a fingerprint in `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/known_hosts` if needed.

Then you can try the `npm` command again.