# Host key verification failed while npm install in ember project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, node-modules, ember-cli

npm install is failing with below error, git clone, npm -v, git pull everything is working fine. This issue I am facing in my cloned repo folder only other places npm install is working fine.

npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

Comment: are you using a private registry?

Comment: not private one

Comment: do you maybe have a bad host key for `github.com`? Could be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806821/npm-install-error-host-key-verification-failed
Also can you maybe share your `package.json`?